# How to determine the number of filled drums, and the room left in each drum

Tags: openoffice-calc

Not quite a homework problem, but it may as well be:

You have a long list of positive integer values stored in column A. These are packets in unit U.
A Drum can fit up to 500 U, but you cannot break up packets.
How many drums are required for any given list of values in column A?

This does not have to be the most efficient answer, processing in row order is absolutely fine.

I Think you should be able to solve this with a formula, but the closest I got was

=CEILING(SUM(A1:A1000)/500;1)

Of course, this breaks up packets.

*Additionally, this problem requires me to be able to find the room left in each drum used, but emphasis for this question should remain on just the number required.*

Comment: Doesn't this belong on https://math.stackexchange.com?

Comment: @marcellothearcane I need to know how to do it in openoffice calc specifically, and there was a tag for it here. I assumed it on-topic here.

Comment: This looks like a [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem).  Such problems are usually solved with code.  Are you open to solutions that use macros, or only spreadsheet formulas?

Comment: @Jim K I'm open to macros, but if an answer would provide a formula later it would be preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be done with a single simple formula.  Each drum and packet needs to be counted.  However contrary to my comment, for this particular problem a spreadsheet works well, and there is no need for a macro.

First, set B2 to `500` for use in other formulas.  If column A is not yet filled, use the formula `=RANDBETWEEN(1,B$2)` to add some values.

Column C is the main formula that determines how full each drum is.  Set C2 to `=A2`.  C3 is `=IF(C2+A3>B$2,A3,C2+A3)`.  Fill C3 down to fill the remaining rows.

For column D, use `=IF(C2+A3>B$2,B$2-C2,"")`.  However the last row of column D is shorter: `=B$2-C21` and change 21 to whatever the last row is.

Finally in column E we find the answer, which is simply `=COUNT(D2:D21)`.

```
Packets  Drum Size  How Full  Room left in each drum used  Number of filled drums
-------  ---------  --------  ---------------------------  ----------------------
206      500        206       294                          13                     
309                 309                                                           
68                  377                                                           
84                  461       39                                                  
305                 305       195                                                 
387                 387       113                                                 
118                 118                                                           
8                   126       374                                                 
479                 479       21                                                  
492                 492       8                                                   
120                 120                                                           
291                 411       89                                                  
262                 262                                                           
108                 370       130                                                 
440                 440       60                                                  
88                  88                                                            
100                 188                                                           
102                 290       210                                                 
478                 478       22                                                  
87                  87        413
```

For OpenOffice Calc, use semicolons `;` instead of commas `,` in formulas.

Comment: Wow, I wish I could upvote this twice. Looks like a lot of work went into this!